# UserWarning: Input dict contained keys which did not match any model input. They will be ignored by the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tf.data.dataset

I try to convert my code to use data.dataset. I'm not far but still have proble with my features and model input layer never seen before I use data.dataset

I load a lot of .csv with many columns for features, csv had heather with name string.

my simple test code is:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import pandas as pd

bd_path = 'C:/Users/my doc/Python/mini_test/'
keep_columns = ['precipitation', 'temperature_min', 'temperature_max',
                'snow_depth_water_equivalent_max', 'streamflow']
name_columns = pd.read_csv(bd_path + 'camels_01022500+attributs_mensuels.csv').columns

# Enable eager execution
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)

# Load a single CSV file and preprocess it
def load_and_preprocess_csv(filename):
    columns = name_columns
    dataset = tf.data.experimental.make_csv_dataset(
        file_pattern=filename,
        num_parallel_reads=2,
        batch_size=32,
        num_epochs=1,
        label_name='streamflow',
        column_names=columns,
        select_columns=keep_columns,
        shuffle_buffer_size=10000,
        header=True,
        field_delim=','
    )

    # Apply preprocessing to the dataset 
    def preprocess_fn(features, label):
        # Normalize the features (example: scaling to [0, 1])
        features['precipitation'] /= 100.0
        features['temperature_min'] /= 100.0
        features['temperature_max'] /= 100.0
        features['snow_depth_water_equivalent_max'] /= 100.0
# last trial I did
        # Create a 'main_inputs' feature by stacking the selected columns
        features['main_inputs'] = tf.stack([
            features['precipitation'],
            features['temperature_min'],
            features['temperature_max'],
            features['snow_depth_water_equivalent_max']
        ], axis=-1)

# here an other trial without sucess...
        # Rename the columns to match the model's input layer
        #features['main_inputs'] = tf.cast(features['main_inputs'], tf.float32)  # Ensure the dtype is correct
        #features['main_inputs'] = tf.identity(features['main_inputs'], name='main_inputs')  # Rename the feature
    
        return features, label

    dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_fn)

    return dataset

# Create a list of file paths matching pattern
file_paths = tf.io.gfile.glob(bd_path + '*.csv')

# Load and preprocess CSV files in parallel
building_datasets = []
for file_path in file_paths:
    dataset = load_and_preprocess_csv(file_path)
    building_datasets.append(dataset)

# Combine the individual datasets into a single dataset
combined_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.sample_from_datasets(building_datasets)

# Optional, further transform, shuffle, and batch the dataset as needed
# For example:
combined_dataset = combined_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)
#combined_dataset = combined_dataset.batch(64)

# model
tensor_input = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(4,), name='main_inputs')
xy = tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='linear')(tensor_input)
xy = tf.keras.layers.Dropout(rate=0.2)(xy)
out = tf.keras.layers.Dense(1, activation='linear')(xy)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=tensor_input, outputs=out)
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001)
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss='mse')

# Train the model
history = model.fit(combined_dataset, epochs=1)
```

the warning I get is:

```
... \keras\engine\functional.py:637: UserWarning: Input dict contained keys ['temperature_min', 'snow_depth_water_equivalent_max', 'temperature_max', 'precipitation'] which did not match any model input. They will be ignored by the model.
```

my experience is passing array directly to model, is the input layer must be modify or this is my dataset who need more modification?

Answer (score 0):

In `preprocess_fn` make sure you use same string to refer to feature indexes -

```
def preprocess_fn(features, label):
    # Normalize the features (example: scaling to [0, 1])
    features['total_precipitation_sum'] /= 100.0
    features['temperature_2m_min'] /= 100.0
    features['temperature_2m_max'] /= 100.0
    features['snow_depth_water_equivalent_max'] /= 100.0
    # last trial I did
    # Create a 'main_inputs' feature by stacking the selected columns
    features['main_inputs'] = tf.stack([
        features['total_precipitation_sum'],
        features['temperature_2m_min'],
        features['temperature_2m_max'],
        features['snow_depth_water_equivalent_max']
    ], axis=-1)

    # here an other trial without sucess...
    # Rename the columns to match the model's input layer
    #features['main_inputs'] = tf.cast(features['main_inputs'], tf.float32)  # Ensure the dtype is correct
    #features['main_inputs'] = tf.identity(features['main_inputs'], name='main_inputs')  # Rename the feature

    # return features, label
    return {'main_inputs': features['main_inputs']}, label    #edited

dataset = dataset.map(preprocess_fn)

return dataset
```

Comment: It is my mistake when writing this question, in my real code all feature are same string, i do the correction here, thank

Comment: try changing return statement of preprocess_fn 
from - 
return dataset
to -
 return {'main_inputs': features['main_inputs']}, label

Comment: It work! Thank so much! Can you explain me what happen? Add your comment as an answer to get your credit

Comment: We can use dictionaries to explicitly specify the input names when mapping inputs to features, I also checked it somewhere online, I was not sure that it would work so I didn't mentioned in my answer.